# touchpad is not working in acer aspiron oneD260

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, synaptics

I am using ubuntu 12.04. touch pad is not detecting in my netbook.  sometimes it is detected and work properly. I try to find list of input device using xinput command.it will not shows the touch pad.its look like software bug. can any one help to rectify this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can try press the "Fn" key plus the "the key with icon a hand"

the touch pad will unlock, so, it is locked by default

Comment: no i tried this and i tried some more many ways as suggested in web. but no use

Comment: some times its working and many times its not working. is it may be bug in the Software? i am using Atom processor with 1GB RAM. may be Lubuntu OS is not suitable for this Hardware( acer D260 netbook)?